# Maven does not resolve org.apache.velocity lib

Tags: java, maven, velocity

***What I have:***

I need to use `org.apache.velocity` in my project. So I add the next strings to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

***Problem:***

But maven doesn't include that lib into `External Libraries` of the project. As result, I can't use those classes. I noticed that maven log contain strings:

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default) @ id----
[INFO] Including org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7 in the shaded jar.
```

***What I've trie:d***

- Clear local maven repo (.m2)
- Rebuil project + all possible maven commands: `clean install`, `clean compile`.. etc.

***P.S.***

On all computer of my colleagues all works well. The use the same IDE, the same project version, all is the same!

***Question:***

*What can I try to resolve my problem?*

***EDIT***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>id</groupId>
    <artifactId>id</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>NAME</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <jackson.version>2.1.1</jackson.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <testng.version>6.8.5</testng.version>
        <tumbler.version>0.4.1</tumbler.version>
        <jmockit.version>1.0</jmockit.version>

        <!-- Plugin versions -->
        <!--<sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.4.1</sonar-maven-plugin.version> -->
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.8.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-assembly-plugin>2.3</maven-assembly-plugin>
        <java.language.version>1.7</java.language.version>
        <groovy.version>2.1.5</groovy.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
            <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>            
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-common</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--String templates-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>id</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>package.name.Main</Main-Class>
                                        <Build-Number>123</Build-Number>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your entire pom.xml ?

Comment: @Adarsh I include my shader-plugin definition into EDIT section of my question

Comment: See if the jar is present in the project classpath and also your local repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you use the maven shade plugin. This plugin will package the artifact in an uber-jar including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the packages of some of the dependencies. This uber-jar is used to package your package and all its dependencies into a single jar to have no outside dependency. This way you distribute your package without taking care about having the right dependencies in the destination.
This plugin is attached to the build phase of your project. You can disable it by commenting its declaration in the pom of your project or in on of its parents.

Comment: I don't want to remove it without understanding what it does for my application. Please include in your answer explanation what it does, when its needed and why all works well with the same pom on other machines

Comment: I've edited my response and included explanation for this plugin usage.

Comment: I removed shader plugin from my pom.xml at all, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I put the whole pom.xml into edit section of my question

Comment: You still don't find your jar ?

Comment: I resolved that problem. I reinstall INTELLIJ IDEA, than remove dependency from `pom.xml`. After that apprears `enable autoimport` dialog, I confirm and IDEA pull the jar by its own. Don't ask me what the problem was.